# Equations with mod 8

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need help answering this math question. What is $$123456789^{25} - 323\times 1212121212 \mod 8$$ I get about half ways and get lost. Please help me figure this out.

Comment: Write your expressions using mathjax. Else they cannot be understood.

Comment: $789^{25}\equiv 789^{25\pmod {4}}\pmod{8}$ by Euler's theorem, so $\equiv 789^{1}\equiv 5\pmod{8}$. Also $323\cdot 212\equiv 3\cdot 4\equiv 12\equiv 4\pmod{8}$.

Comment: In general $\overline{a_na_{n-1}\cdots a_2a_1a_0}\equiv \overline{a_2a_1a_0}\pmod{8}$.

Comment: @Mikaela, for now I have re-written your expression with mathJAX, to learn how to do it, see 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Should the exponent be 2 or 25?

Comment: Hint: $123456789\equiv5\pmod 8$, so $123456789^2\equiv5^2=25\equiv1\pmod8$; and $323\equiv3\pmod8$ and $1212121212\equiv4\pmod 8$. This should make it easy to answer the original question, in your head even! This is the moral of problems like this: always reduce early on, to make the arithmetic easier.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 1 and it goes as: 789^25-212. Now the group of units is isomorphic with Z_2+Z_2 and so the maximal order is 2. Thus 789^25=789^1=5. And 212=4. The answer is 1.

Comment: In my opinion, the reduction of the original numbers doesn't go far enough. See my comment on the main question.